# creating a WordPress theme from scratch using bootstrap and getting error

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating a WordPress theme from scratch using Bootstrap.
In my index file i have left the sample post and then i am looping through and trying to see if there is another post present. Doing this i am getting an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in
>   C:\wamp\www\wordpress-bootstrap\bootstrap\wp-content\themes\wpbootstrap\index.php
>   on line 49

**The code is :**

```
<!--we have left the first blog post here and removed the next two now we are wrapping a loop around it .
now we are trying to check if there are blog posts. -->
<?php if(have_posts());?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <div class="blog-post">
            <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
            <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

            <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that's supported and styled with Bootstrap. Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
            <blockquote>
              <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong> ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
            <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
            <pre><code>Example code block</code></pre>
            <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
            <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</li>
              <li>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</li>
              <li>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
            <ol>
              <li>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</li>
              <li>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</li>
              <li>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</li>
            </ol>
            <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.</p>
          </div><!-- /.blog-post -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<!--this is in continuation for the checking of blog post loop-->
<?php else : ?>
  <p><?php __('No Posts Found'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any Help will be appriciated. Thank You In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `if()` statement, it should be:

```
<?php if(have_posts()): ?>
```

<sup>*You had `;` instead of* ***`:`***.</sup>

Comment: do you have any resource suggestions for learning wordpress in depth that you might have followed.

Comment: This problem wasn't so much WordPress, it was more PHP - but the [WordPress site itself](https://codex.wordpress.org/New_To_WordPress_-_Where_to_Start) is a great place!